# Why Jetpack Compose BOM version take the latest depenency , not the version specified on Bom Mappings

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using the "androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.06.01" on my  gradle dependency , but when i ran the  "./gradlew app:dependencies;"

Could someone explain me why it's resolved to latest one ?

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // Support libraries
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activityVersion"

    // Fragment
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragmentktxVersion"

    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$corektxVersion"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$androidxCardViewVersion"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintlayoutVersion"
    implementation "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:$androidxGridLayoutVersion"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerviewVersion"
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:$preferenceVersion"
    implementation "androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:$androidxVectordrawableVersion"
    implementation "androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:$androidxVectordrawableAnimatedVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$materialVersion"

    // Google libraries
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:17.0.0")
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:18.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$googleGsonVersion"



    // Firebase
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:$firebaseVersion")
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display-ktx'



    // Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$gsonVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp3Version"

    // Rx
    implementation "io.reactivex:rxjava:$rxjavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex:rxandroid:$rxandroidVersion"


    // Timber
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$timberVersion"

    // Dagger
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'


    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'





  








    //compose
    def composeBom = platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:$composeBOMVersion")
    implementation composeBom
    androidTestImplementation composeBom

    implementation ("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation ("androidx.compose.material:material")
    implementation ("androidx.activity:activity-compose")
    implementation ("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata")
    implementation ("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime")
    implementation ("androidx.compose.animation:animation")
    implementation ("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation")
    implementation ("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout")
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose")
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate")
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose")
    implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$composeNavigationVersion")

    // Android Studio Preview support
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'


    implementation ("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-swiperefresh:$accompanistSwiperefreshVersion")

    //Splash screen
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1'

    // UI Tests
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutinesAndroidVersion"


// testing

}


 ext {
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        minSdkVersion = 24

        kotlinVersion = '1.7.21'

        activityVersion = "1.5.1"
        appCompatVersion = '1.5.1'
        appCompatResourcesVersion = "1.6.1"
        fragmentktxVersion="1.5.4"
        corektxVersion="1.8.0"
        androidxCardViewVersion = '1.0.0'
        androidxGridLayoutVersion = '1.0.0'
        androidxVectordrawableVersion = '1.0.0'
        androidxVectordrawableAnimatedVersion = '1.0.0'
        androidxAnnotations = "1.6.0"

        viewModelktxVersion="2.6.1"

        androidxSqliteVersion="2.1.0"

        constraintlayoutVersion = "2.1.4"
        recyclerviewVersion = "1.3.0"
        preferenceVersion = "1.1.1"
        materialVersion = "1.1.0"

        securityCryptoVersion = "1.0.0"

        googleGsonVersion = '2.8.9'
        daggerVersion = '2.42'

        amplifyVersion = "1.38.7"
        amplifyKotlinVersion="0.22.7"
        desugarVersion = "1.1.5"

        playServicesVersion = '18.1.0'

        firebaseVersion = '32.1.1'

        dbflowVersion = "4.2.4"

        workManagerVersion = "2.7.1"

        usabillaVersion = "7.3.5"

        retrofitVersion = "2.7.0"
        gsonVersion = "2.6.1"
        okhttp3Version = "4.2.1"
        okhttpInterceptorVersion = "4.9.1"

        rxjavaVersion="1.3.8"
        rxandroidVersion="1.2.1"

        coroutinesAndroidVersion="1.3.9"
        coroutinesPlayServicesVersion="1.6.4"

        composeBOMVersion = "2023.06.01"
        composeCompilerVersion="1.4.0-alpha02"
        composeNavigationVersion = "2.5.3"
        immutableLibVersion = "0.3.5"
        accompanistDrawablePainterVersion = "0.31.5-beta"
        accompanistSwiperefreshVersion = "0.25.1"
        coilComposeVersion = "2.4.0" //Not Compatible with current dependencies

        newRelicVersion = '6.10.0'
        leakCanaryVersion = "2.7"
        timberVersion = "4.7.1"
        ktlintVersion="0.35.0"

        jetbrainAnnotationVersion = "24.0.1"

        //Testing
        junitVersion="4.13.2"
        mockkVersion="1.13.5"
        coroutines_test="1.7.3"
        turbine="1.0.0"
        androidxTextCoreVersion = "1.5.0"
        mockitoCoreVersion = "5.3.0"
        robolectricVersion = "4.9"
        junitExtVersion = "1.1.5"
        espressoVersion = "3.5.1"

    }
```

dependency get resolved to "*:1.5.0-beta03"
[image]
Expected this
[image]

Comment: can you share your gradle please!!

Comment: update  with dependencies and versions

Comment: Happens to me as well. Do you managed to find a solution or explanation for that? @Sam

Comment: if you run a gradle `--scan` you'll get more information, and you can see which of your dependencies is transitively depending on a newer version of compose